# Copying out NSEntity, swapping coredata, resaving NSEntity

Tags: ios, core-data

I have a database with coredata, that saves favourites as well as the items that make up that favourite.

I have to update the database with a new one, so I need to copy out all the users favourites into a temp storage, swap the database then resave the Favourites back into the database.

My problem is, when I try and copy out the Favourites, it only copys out the attributes of the favourites, and none of the relationship data.

So when the Favourites resaves, it will have name, and title (both favourites attributes), but then all other info is set to null.

My question is, how do I do a deep copy of a NSEntity while keeping all relational info intact.

Comment: [MIGRATION](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/CoreDataVersioning/Articles/Introduction.html) is not an option? As CoreData is an object graph you can use any [TRAVERSAL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_traversal) method that feet your needs. relationships are available for traversal through `[entity relationshipsByName]` (see [HERE](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSEntityDescription_Class/NSEntityDescription.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSEntityDescription/relationshipsByName))

Comment: Migration is not an option for us, which is why we are trying to do it this way.